# HTTPS calls are not working in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, api, axios

I am developing an API call in React Native using `Axios` but I am not able to hit the backend after release using  `./gradlew assembleRelease`. in debugging mode the calls are happening, but I don't understand why it is not happening in Build Release. Where's the backend is developed in Node & Express.

Heres the code I am attaching:

`App.tsx`

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
       getData().then(d => {
           setData(d.data)
       })
    }, [getData])
```

`Services.ts`

```
    const getData = async () => {
        axios.defaults.headers.Accept = "application/json";
        return axios.get(`https://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/course`)
            .then((resultant) => {
                console.log(resultant)
                return resultant.data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
}
export {getData}
```

Comment: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true". in you manifest file

Answer (score 0):

did you set proper permissions for your app in androidManifest?
and btw, why don't you try "./gradlew bundleRelease"?

Comment: How to set permissions in AndroidManifest for `https` ?. I checked with `./gradlew bundleRelease` same issue. :(